# Push notification not coming in curtain (Notification bar) testing in Android Ionic 4

Tags: push-notification, ionic4, cordova-plugin-fcm

I am using `ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-fcm-with-dependecy-updated` plugin for push notifications . I am getting the device token but when i am sending the notification getting the notifications data in the console but notification is not coming in-app curtain. Please suggest if you have link or solution.

Comment: Is the app running at the time? It only appears as a notification if the app is not running and focused.

Comment: @rtpHarry actually push notification is not coming in any state. Not in the background or in the foreground but I can the see the messages in the console